# PHP: I can't get the capital to be called out when I type a country into a form?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, countries

I am new to PHP. I am creating a program that based on a country you submit in a form, the output is a capital of that country. I ran into a problem. I can get the corresponding element in the array called out, but I can't get it to be called out based on the form submission. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php 
$capitals = array("Algeria"=>"Algiers", "Argentina"=>"Buenos Aires", "Australia"=>"Canberra", "Belgium"=>"Minsk", "Bolivia"=>"Sucre", "Bosnia & Herzegovina"=>"Sarajevo", "Brazil"=>"Brasilia", "Bulgaria"=>"Sofia", "Cambodia"=>"Phnom Penh", "Cameroon"=>"Yaounde", "Canada"=>"Ottawa", "Chile"=>"Santiago", "China"=>"Beijing", "Colombia"=> "Bogota", "Costa Rica"=>"San Jose", "Croatia"=>"Zagreb", "Cuba"=>"Havana", "Czech Republic"=>"Prague", "Denmark"=>"Copenhagen", "Ecuador"=>"Quito", "Egypt"=>"Cairo", "Finland"=>"Helsinki", "France"=>"Paris", "Germany"=>"Berlin", "Ghana"=>"Accra", "Greece"=>"Athens", "Honduras"=>"Tegucigalpa", "Hungary"=>"Budapest", "Iceland"=>"Reykjavik", "India"=>"New Delhi", "Indonesia"=>"Jakarta", "Iran"=>"Tehran", "Iraq"=>"Baghdad", "Ireland"=>"Dublin", "Israel"=>"Jerusalem", "Italy"=>"Rome", "Jamaica"=>"Kingston", "Japan"=>"Tokyo", "Jordan"=>"Ammman", "Kazakhstan"=>"Nur-Sultan", "Kenya"=>"Nairobi", "Kosovo"=>"Pristina", "Kuwait"=>"Kuwait City", "Lebanon"=>"Beirgut", "Libya"=>"Tripoli", "Lithuania"=>"Vilnius", "Luxembourg"=>"Luxembourg", "Madagascar"=>"Antananarivo", "Malaysia"=>"Kuala Lumpur", "Maldives"=>"Male", "Malta"=>"Vakketta", "Marshall Islands"=>"Majuro", "Mexico"=>"Mexico City", "Monaco"=>"Monaco", "Morocco"=>"Rabat", "Nepal"=>"Kathmandu", "Netherlands"=>"Amsterdam", "New Zealand"=>"Wellington", "Nigeria"=>"Abuja", "North Korea"=>"Pyongyang", "Norway"=>"Oslo", "Palestine"=>"East Jerusalem", "Panama"=>"Panama City", "Paraguay"=>"Asuncion", "Peru"=>"Lima", "Philippines"=>"Manila", "Poland"=>"Warsaw", "Portugal"=>"Lisbon", "Qatar"=>"Doha", "Romania"=>"Bucharest", "Russia"=>"Moscow", "San Marino"=>"San Marino", "Saudi Arabia"=>"Riyadh", "Senegal"=>"Dakar", "Serbia"=>"Belgrade", "Sierra Leone"=>"Freetown", "Singapore"=>"Singapore", "Slovakia"=>"Bratislava", "Slovenia"=>"Ljubljana", "South Africa"=>"Bloemfontein, Cape Town, Pretoria", "South Korea"=>"Seoul", "Spain"=>"Madrid", "Sweden"=>"Stockholm",
"Switzerland"=>"Bern", "Syria"=>"Damascus", "Trinidad & Tobago"=>"Port of Spain", "Tunisia"=>"Tunis", "Turkey"=>"Ankara", "Uganda"=>"Kampala", "Ukraine"=>"Kiev", "United Arab Emirates"=>"Abu Dhabi", "United Kingdom"=>
"London", "United States"=>"Washington D.C.", "Uruguay"=>"Montevideo", "Vietnam"=>"Hanoi", "Yemen"=>"Sana'a", "Zimbabwe"=>"Harare"); 


foreach($capitals as $countries=>$capitals)
{
    print("The capital of $countries is $capitals <br>");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Form Code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="capitals.php" method="post">

Country: <input type = "text" name="country">


<input type="submit"><br>

</form>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Where and how are you using the data from the input?

Comment: Side note: If that is your actual code, you didn't close this off `</html`

Comment: It's not a good idea to reuse the variable `$capitals` like that. After the loop, `$capitals` will contain the last capital, not the array.

Comment: Instead of foreach you should print the value of array where key matches your country. Something like - echo $capitals[$_POST['country']]; you can also check the existence of the country by using isset() function. I am not giving you complete code as you are learning and direct help is not good while learning.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$output = 'not found';
if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
    $inputCountry = $_POST['country'];
    if (isset($capitals[$inputCountry])) {
        $capital = $capitals[$inputCountry];
    }
    $output = "The capital of $inputCountry is $capital <br>";
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is great because the code you provided works, the only problem is it returns the output on a never ending loop.

Comment: @Hubert Im not sure what you mean, can you show your updated code? For what its worth, you don't need the `foreach` loop at all with this approach, if you maybe added this inside that loop, you can remove that

Comment: foreach($capitals as $countries=>$capital)
{
$output = 'not found';
if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
    $inputCountry = $_POST['country'];
    if (isset($capitals[$inputCountry])) {
        $capital = $capitals[$inputCountry];
    }
    $output = "The capital of $inputCountry is $capital <br>";
}
echo $output;
}          this is the updated code, it returns exactly what I want, but instead of returning it ones it returns it over and over again over 50 times

Comment: @Hubert, yeah, ditch that foreach loop completely and leave only the code that was inside it  and you should be good :)

Comment: Thank you so much, everything you said worked:) As you can tell I am  a total noob when it comes to PHP, so thanks for bearing with me.